# Open source cocos2d racing game

Tags: iphone, ios, open-source

I'm looking for racing game cocos2d open source project. Is there any? or even a pointer / tutorial for it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is not a racing game but I created a Tilemap game called "Math Speeder". A similar game "Desert Race" is available on Github. You can see the source code at the following link:

https://github.com/azamsharp/Desert-Race

Answer (score 2):

http://www.barlow-server.com/tuxriderworldchallenge/

Try this.. and i hope it can help you :)